# Is there a Visual Studio option or add-on to add an "Open Explorer Here" when I right click on a project in the solution folder?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

When I right click on a project in the solution explorer I'd like to be able to select an option that would open a new windows "Explorer" that lists the contents of the build directory.  I'd settle for the project directory... but getting me into /bin/x86/Debug vs /bin/x86/Release based on the active build configuration would be major bonus.

I find myself manually navigating to that folder fairly often for various reasons - usually on Utility applications which don't have installers / cmd line build scripts etc

I currently use 2005 express.  But, am open to upgrading.

Comment: Note in VS 2010 there is an "Open Foldre in Windows Explorer" option in the project right click menu

Comment: @JaredPar that's a step in the right direction.  It opens to the project directory not the build directory though I assume?

Comment: correct it opens the project dir

Answer (score 2):

A couple things that might be close enough:

- add an "external tool" to the Tools menu. In the "Tools | External Tools..." dialog:

  - Click "Add" and give the new tool whatever name you want
  - Command: `%systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe`
  - Argument: `/k "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86`
  - Initial directory: `$(TargetDir)` // (or whatever appropriate macro)
- Right click on a open document's tab and select "Open containing folder"

My VS 2005 Standard IDE already had a "Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt" tool, but it landed the command window in the VC installation directory.  Changing the "Argument" and "Initial directory" fields as above made it land in the project's target directory.

The drawbacks are they don't show up in the right menu for the project and they might not land you exactly where you want, but they should land you pretty close.

Comment: Thanks that's a pretty good start.  $(TargetDir) puts me in project-name/obj instead of /bin.  From the looks of the external tool variable reference, there doesn't appear to be a better variable... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekbzk5f8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Try `$(BinDir)` or `$(BinDir)\..` to see if they work better for you.

Comment: No Dice, just item/project/target or solution are the only options :/

Comment: $(ProjectDir)\bin\x86\Debug does get me to the right folder... assuming I always am using that build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No sure this is what you want but the "Open file" icon will pop up a FileOpen dialog in the project folder. From there you can right click the Release or Debug folders to open them in an Explorer (and Cancel the dialog).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But, pretty clunky.